# RegExp avoid double space and space before characters

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to write a regular expression in order to not allow double spaces anywhere in a string, and also force a single space before a `MO` or `GO` mandatory, with no space allowed at the beginning and at the end of the string.

**Example 1** : `It is 40 GO` right

**Example 2** : `It is 40GO` wrong

**Example 3** : `It is  40 GO` wrong

Here's what I've done so far `^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ,()]*[^;'][^ ]$`, which prevents spaces at the beginning and at the end, and also the ";" character. This one works like a charm.

My issue is not allowing double spaces anywhere in the string, and also forcing spaces right before `MO` or `GO` characters.

After a few hours of research, I've tried these (starting from the previous RegExp I wrote):

To prevent the double spaces: `^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ,()]*((?!.* {2}).+)[^;'][^ ]$`

To force a single space before `MO`: `^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ,()]*(?=\sMO)*[^;'][^ ]$`

But neither of the last two actually work. I'd be thankful to anyone that helps me figure this out

Comment: Why do you have this? `[^;']` Should the second last character be any character except `;` and `'`? The thing with this pattern `^[^ ][a-zA-Z0-9 ,()]*((?!.* {2}).+)[^;'][^ ]$` is that is should be at least 4 characters long, and the last pattern has a quantifier after a lookaround `(?=\sMO)*` Can you update the question with examples that should and should not match to make it more clear?

Comment: I have it because the string must not have any single quote or semi-colon. I'll edit the question with example immediately

Comment: Perhaps try it like this `^(?!.*\S[MG]O\b)[a-zA-Z0-9,()]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9,()]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/poDRsc/1

Comment: Does this work for all your cases? [`^(?! )(?!.* $)(?!.*?\s{2,})(?!.*\S[MG]O).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/hwMf5i/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution worked, thank you very much ! Can you just explain this part though ? ```(?!.*\S[MG]O\b)``` From what I saw, it's called ```lookahead```, and I knew I needed it but wasn't sure how it works

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh yes it covers all my needs, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookahead `(?!.* {2}` can be omitted, and instead start the match with a non whitespace character and end the match with a non whitespace character and use a single space in an optionally repeated group.

If the string can not contain a `'` or `;` then using `[^;'][^ ]$` means that the second last character should not be any of those characters.

But you can omit that part, as the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9,()]` does not match  `;` and `'`

Note that using a character class like `[^ ]` and `[^;']` actually expect a single character, making the pattern that you tried having a minimum length.

Instead, you can rule out the presence of GO or MO preceded by a non whitespace character.

```
^(?!.*\S[MG]O\b)[a-zA-Z0-9,()]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9,()]+)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\S[MG]O\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not a non whitspace character followed by either `MO` or `GO` to the right. The word boundary `\b` prevents a partial word match
- `[a-zA-Z0-9,()]+` Start the match with 1+ occurrences of any of the listed characters (Note that there is no space in it)
- `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9,()]+)*` Optionally repeat the same character class with a leading space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/poDRsc/1)